# Form control in Django ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

My Models:

```
class Faculty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
```

Let I have Two Faculty:

- Science
- Management

And I have 3 Programs in each:

- Science

  - B. Computer
  - B. Software
  - B. Civil
- Management

  - BBA
  - BBS
  - BBI

And What I want is When A studen Is Filling up a Form They can Select Faculty and Programs. So When a user select Science as Faculty. Then How to make django Gives Only Programs From That selected Faculty? That means when users select Science in Faculty Field Then in program field Computer, Software and Civil should be Shown.

Is it possible? then how? I think I make a clear question. (easy to understand what I mean)

**Update:-** as asked By @thameem

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = {'name','faculty','program','roll','gender','contact','address','about',}
```

Template:

```
<div class="contener">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}

            <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^addprofile/$', addprofile, name='addprofile'),
]
```

Comment: Start a bounty, this will be a long but straight forward answer.

Comment: I really don't understand what you really mean. So according to you it is impossible like for now?

Comment: It can be done but no one will do it for free because you question is not highly rated nor you have put a bounty in it.

Comment: I will Surely do it If I have that Privilege or So called. I am very Need of that solution and For that I may need to Answers some unanswered questions. (just by searching the solution on web). Will earn some reputation and will put a bounty on it.

Comment: shows your forms.py and html template and urls.py

Comment: @thameem I am Very beginner So there is not special things I do. I Update the post as Requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can done it by using ajax

put this code in your template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("select[name='faculty']").change(function(){
            var value =  $(this).val();
            var pselect = $("select[name='program']");

            $.ajax({
                method:"get",
                dataType:"json",
                url:'{% url 'profile:suggest_program' %}',
                data:{
                'faculty':value
                },
                success:function(data){
                    pselect.empty();
                    $.each(data, function(index, value){
                        pselect.append("<option value='"+value.pk+"'>"+value.name+"</option>");
                    });
                },

            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

in your views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def suggest_program(request):
    faculty = request.GET.get("faculty")
    programs = [{"data":"nothing found"}]
    if faculty:
        programs = Program.objects.filter(faculty_id=faculty
                                            ).values("pk", "name")
        programs = list(programs)
    return JsonResponse(programs, safe=False)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^suggest-program/$', views.suggest_program, name="suggest_program"),
```

Comment: got this on url /suggest-program/  `[{"data": "nothing found"}]`

Comment: try like this in url ..suggest-program/?faculty=1

Comment: you know jqyery. did you put that code in your html

Comment: I dont for now. Will go through it now to make it work.

Comment: Ya now in that existing Template. that I shows above. git error 'profile' is not a registered namespace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142344/discussion-between-devkota-sagar-and-thameem).

Comment: change this to your actual path '{%  url 'profile:suggest_program' %}',  to 
'/suggest-program/',