# How to ask for login to access to any url django

Tags: python, django

I have thies in views.py

```
 @login_required()
 def dadmin(request):
```

I had not used @login_required() in dapost and dapage

And in url.py

```
url(r'^dadmin/$', dadmin, name='dadmin'),
url(r'^dadmin/post/$', dapost, name='dapost'),
url(r'^dadmin/page/$', dapage, name='dapage'),
```

Now I want is everytime when users try to access domain.com/dadmin/any... it redirect to login page. how ca i Do that? without placing @login_required() in dapost and dapage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it by using custom middleware

save this as `custom_middleware.py` file in your main app

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class CheckUser(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):

        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if not request.user.is_authenticated() and \
                        request.path.startswith('/dadmin/'):
            return redirect("/login/")

        response = self.get_response(request)


        return response
```

and in your `settings.py`  edit the  `middleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #custom middlewares
    'app.custom_middleware.CheckUser'
]
```

Comment: It Worked. SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' in Python3 ___ **to fix for python3**  `print "init working"` to `print ("init working")` Thank you!

Comment: @DevkotaSagar remove that line print ("init working"). that i used for debugging

Comment: Ok so can def __init__(self, get_response):  be removed too?

Comment: no. it is a constructor to initialize get_response. just gothrough this link to know more about middlewares . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: i made a small changes in that code. put our condition above this self.get_response(request) function call. Because here we need to execute our call before our view get called. please go throught above link. you will get more clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much Can you please answer this or make anyone to answer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478355/form-control-in-django-foreignkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478355/form-control-in-django-foreignkey)

Answer (score 0):

If you set LOGIN_URL in your settings.py:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#login-url

all anonymous users will be redirected when accessing to urls with login_required() decorator in their views.

Edit: you can make a custom LoginRequiredMiddleware too, with the path you desire.

Comment: I want redirect to login to any link accessed like  .com/dadmin/post or .com/dadmin/page or .com/dadmin/(anything).  not only to that from views.py

Comment: Why don't you put the decorator in dapost, dapage and all views that needs this behavior?

Comment: You can make a custom LoginRequiredMiddleware too, with the path you desire. Edited in the answer.